# Drag & drop file containing comma (,) in filename on a .bat file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

When drag-and-dropping a file named `test(a23,b824).txt` on this `test.bat`:

```
echo %1
```

we get `D:\temp\test(a23` instead of the full filename.

I tried variations like `echo %~1`, `echo "%1"`, but none of them work. Also     `echo %1,%2` would work in this specific case, but how to find a solution that works for

```
test(a23).txt
test(a23,b824).txt
test(a23,b824,c173).txt
```

?

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Batch file Copy using %1 for drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14786623/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related: [How to Invoke a parameter in a batch file with comma-delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145744/how-to-invoke-a-parameter-in-a-batch-file-with-comma-delimiter)

Depending on what you do use `%*` instead. Depending on what you do you might still have issues.